# Trying to get a checkboxGroupInput derived from column values to filter a bar graph, but keep getting various errors?

Tags: r, shiny

I keep getting errors like Error in  : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable or

'..1'. x Input '..1' must be of size 28 or 1, not size 0. I am trying to change the bar graph based on what options are selected or not in the checkbox.

I changed the column names for ease of use from where I got the data.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


#dataset link: https://www.kaggle.com/mahirahmzh/starbucks-customer-retention-malaysia-survey?select=Starbucks+satisfactory+survey.csv

#c("Timestamp","Gender","age","currently","income","visit_freq","Enjoy","Time","Nearby","membership","freq_purchase","avg_spend","Ratevsother","rateprice","salesandpromotion","ambiance","wifi","service","meetup","heardaboutpromotions","continuepatronage")

data <-read.csv("Starbucks satisfactory survey.csv", header=TRUE)

Categorical.Variables <- c("visit_freq", "age", "income")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('category', choices = Categorical.Variables, label = 'Select filter options:'), 
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.category != '-'",
                     uiOutput("select_category"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$select_category <- renderUI({
    
    choices <- as.list(unique(data[[input$category]]))
    
    checkboxGroupInput('categorycheck', label = 'Select filter:',
                       choices = choices,selected = choices)
    
    data2 <- reactive({
      data %>% 
      group_by(gender,data[[input$category]], currently,membership) %>%
      summarize(n = n(), .groups="drop") %>%
      filter(data[[input$category]] %in% input$categorycheck) %>%
      filter(membership == "Yes")})
    
    renderPlotly({
      data2 <- data2()
      colnames(data2) <- c("gender","filtercategory","currently","membership","n")
      plot_ly(data2, x = ~currently, y = ~n, type = "bar", color=~gender,  colors="Dark2") %>%
        layout(barmode = 'group')
    })
    
     
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues.  You should close your `renderUI` prior to using `input$categorycheck` in the reactive object `data2`.  In addition, columns names in the csv file are long.  Once you define the column names of `data` the way you are analyzing, it will work.  Try this

```
mydata <-read.csv("Starbucks satisfactory survey.csv", header=TRUE)
names(mydata)[1:10] <- c("Timestamp", "gender", "Age", "currently", "Income", "visit_freq","drink_freq","time_spent", "nearby","membership")

Categorical.Variables <-  c("Age", "Income", "visit_freq")

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('category', choices = Categorical.Variables, label = 'Select filter options:'),
    #conditionalPanel(condition = "input.category != '-'",
                     uiOutput("select_category")
                    # )
  ),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("myplot"),
            DTOutput("t1")
            )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$select_category <- renderUI({
    req(input$category)
    choices <- as.list(unique(mydata[[input$category]]))

    checkboxGroupInput('categorycheck', label = 'Select filter:',
                       choices = choices,selected = choices)
  })

    data2 <- reactive({
      req(input$category,input$categorycheck)
      
      mydata %>%
        group_by(gender,.data[[input$category]], currently,membership) %>%
        dplyr::summarize(n = n(), .groups="drop") %>%
        filter(.data[[input$category]] %in% input$categorycheck) %>%
        filter(membership == "Yes")})
    output$t1 <- renderDT(data2())

  output$myplot <-  renderPlotly({
    req(data2())
      data2 <- data2()
      colnames(data2) <- c("gender","filtercategory","currently","membership","n")
      plot_ly(data2, x = ~currently, y = ~n, type = "bar", color=~gender,  colors="Dark2") %>%
        layout(barmode = 'group')

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I am still getting an error [31mx[39m Input `..1` must be of size 36 or 1, not size 122.

Comment: data is linked in the original post as well as a comment about changing the column names. https://www.kaggle.com/mahirahmzh/starbucks-customer-retention-malaysia-survey?select=Starbucks+satisfactory+survey.csv

Comment: I copied and pasted the exact code with a new dataset keep getting an Errors:
force(ui) : object 'ui' not found
Error in plotlyOutput$myplot <- renderPlotly({ :

Comment: Please check to make sure that you can run the above code as is.

Comment: I cant run the code as is. I keep getting errors.

Comment: Please note that when you change the dataset name, only the original data name should be changed. `.data[[input$category)]]` should remain the same.

Comment: Also, please ensure that you have "Starbucks satisfactory survey.csv" file in your work directory (folder) where you keep your `app.R` file.

Comment: I set the working directory to the file location and put in the app.r file it still did not work. The dataset name is as suggested.

Comment: If this code does not work for you as is, then you have some other problem.  Perhaps you need to update RStudio and/or R version.

Comment: I restarted my computer and for some reason it works now. Thanks!